# Numerical Linear Algebra - eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I am coming from the programming world, and I am currently trying to solve a finding eigenvalues problem in a code. HOwever I find it as a very difficult problem to solve in higher matrices dimensions. For 2x2, and 3x3 matrices I found this wikipedia that shows an algorithm for this problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm (Direct calculation).

I also read about Jacobi-Davidson solution, but I could not understand how does it works.

The question is what algorithm should I use to calculate the eigenvalues for higher dimensions matrices?

Comment: Many languages have packages that do this job. Some allow you to choose an algorithm appropriate for the kind of matrix you are interested in. I think you will be better served researching that than asking an open ended question here.

Comment: In the first place, you need to know if the matrix is real/complex, and symmetric/Hermitian. And if you also need the Eigenvectors.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have never stopped looking for a way.

Comment: @YvesDaoust the matrix is real. For the symmetric/Hermitian I can check it inside the code (it's unknown when I run the algorithm). For the eigenvectors- Whenever I find the eigenvalues, I will be able to find the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2):

The Jacobi methods works by diagonalizing the matrix, i.e. finding a decomposition

$$M=PDP^{-1}$$ or $$D=P^{-1}MP,$$
where $D$ is diagonal.

This is done iteratively by means of Givens rotations (elementary matrix transforms), which allow canceling one matrix element at a time. During the algorithm,

$$R_n^{-1}\cdots R_2^{-1}R_1^{-1}MR_1R_2\cdots R_n=D_n$$ and $D_n$ tends to a diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

One of the popular methods for finding eigenvalues is the [power iteration method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).

It is about calculating successive matrix-vector products $$\bf v_{n+1} = Av_n$$ and 
Starting with a random vector $\bf v_0$, and finishing when element-wise division $$\frac{\bf v_{n+1}}{\bf v_n}$$
produces close to the same value, then this value will be the largest eigenvalue.

If it still has not produced close to same value, then performing a normalization after each step $$\bf v_n = \frac{v_n}{|v_n|}$$

---

Once you found the largest, then you store the vector $\bf v_n=w_1$, and you restart the algorithm with a new random vector, but this time you start with **projecting away the previously known eigenvectors**

$$\bf v_0 = v_0 - w_1\frac{(v_0 \cdot w_1)}{\|v_0\|}$$

This way you will be sure that no part of this new random vector will start growing in the direction of the old found eigenvector.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am looking for a way to find all of the eigenvalues of the matrix, and not only the largest one.

Comment: @KorelK ok I added description how to iterate for more